# Share data between different test classes

Tags: python, django, testing, django-1.8

I have a dedicated test class for each different component I need to test in a particular module. All these tests revolve around the same object/context so it could be an improvement in performance if the corresponding objects weren't created and inserted in the test database and then deleted for every single test class:

```
class ContextTest(TestCase):
    fixtures = [...]

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        pass

# executes setUpTestData
class Component1Test(ContextTest):
    pass

# executes setUpTestData again
class Component2Test(ContextTest):
    pass
```

Is there any way I can ensure that `setUpTestData` is run only once, while keeping my tests under different classes for clarity's sake?

Answer (score 2):

I put my tests in mixin classes derived from `object` and then made a single class that derived from `TestCase` but mixed in the mixins that have the actual tests.

```
class A(object):
   ...

class B(object):
   ...

class TestAll(A, B, TestCase):

   @classmethod 
   def setUpTestData(class):
      ...
```

Just be careful not to use the same method names in `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [setUpClass](http:///docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase)!)

Comment: mmm no, you can't load data in that method